# how to use get_user to copy data from user space to kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to copy an integer variable from user space to kernel space.
Can anyone give me a simple example how to do this?
I came to know that we can use get_user but i am unable to know how..

Comment: [IOCTL](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html#ss4.1) is a way to transfer data between user & kernel space.

Answer (score 0):

Check `man` pages of `copy_to_user` and `copy_from_user`.
Write a simple kernel module, with `read/write` operations, and register and char device for them, something like `/dev/sample`.
Do an application `write/read`, on `fd` opened by this application.
Now you need to implement the mechanism for transferring this data to kernel space and read back whatever returned.
- In `write` you do a `copy_from_user`, before this check passed buffer is valid or not.
- In `read` you do a `copy_to_user`.
Make sure error conditions are taken care of, and `open` call implementation should keep track of how many `opens` are there, if you want to implement multiple open, and this count should be decremented, when application calls a `close` on opened `FD`.
Do you follow ?

Comment: can you explain the procedure more detailed please. It's hard for me to understand this. Thanks